# K8s metallb load balancer IP not reachable sometimes

Tags: kubernetes, dhcp, metallb

I have on-premise k8s cluster with 3 masters and 4 workers. Metallb is installed and DHCP is provided for him from the same network as on-premise cluster IPs.

I tried to start Kubernetes Dashboard app in the cluster and everything is working fine except LoadBalancer type of Service of Kubernetes Dashboard:

```
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  annotations:
    metallb.universe.tf/address-pool: single-ip
  labels:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 443
      targetPort: 8443
  selector:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  externalIPs:
   - 192.168.1.129
```

```
root@master1:/# kubectl get services -n kubernetes-dashboard
NAME                        TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP       PORT(S)         AGE
dashboard-metrics-scraper   ClusterIP      10.249.40.230   <none>            8000/TCP        6h8m
kubernetes-dashboard        LoadBalancer   10.249.3.22     192.168.1.129   443:32593/TCP   6h8m
```

After applying all configs dashboard is starting to work at https://192.168.1.129 from cluster and from my computer correctly.

But after **some time** stopped to work from my computer but continue to work from cluster. From my computer I'm getting "Connection refused error".

From my computer and from cluster 192.168.1.129 IP is pinging normally without any problems.

externalTrafficPolicy is Cluster by default. Changing it to Local didn't help.

What's happening? How to resolve issue when service working and then stopping to work and then again starting to work? :)

Answer (score 0):

One way for me to make it work again is to change a value in the MetalLB configuration to get it reloaded.

*EDIT:*

After changing `externalTrafficPolicy` from `Local` to `Cluster` it seems stable for me.

*According the documentation: https://metallb.universe.tf/usage/*

> Layer2 When announcing in layer2 mode, one node in your cluster will
> attract traffic for the service IP. From there, the behavior depends
> on the selected traffic policy.
>
> “Cluster” traffic policy With the default Cluster traffic policy,
> kube-proxy on the node that received the traffic does load balancing,
> and distributes the traffic to all the pods in your service.
>
> This policy results in uniform traffic distribution across all pods in
> the service. However, kube-proxy will obscure the source IP address of
> the connection when it does load balancing, so your pod logs will show
> that external traffic appears to be coming from the service’s leader
> node.
>
> “Local” traffic policy With the Local traffic policy, kube-proxy on
> the node that received the traffic sends it only to the service’s
> pod(s) that are on the same node. There is no “horizontal” traffic
> flow between nodes.
>
> Because kube-proxy doesn’t need to send traffic between cluster nodes,
> your pods can see the real source IP address of incoming connections.
>
> The downside of this policy is that incoming traffic only goes to some
> pods in the service. Pods that aren’t on the current leader node
> receive no traffic, they are just there as replicas in case a failover
> is needed.